# 2 dimensional array & method calls - beginner

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a homework assignment for a beginner-level class and I need help building a program that tests if a sodoku solution presented as an int[][] is valid. I do this by creating helper methods that check both rows, columns and grids.

To check the column I call a method called getColumn that returns a column[]. When I test it out it works fine. I then pass it out on a method called uniqueEntries that makes sure that there are no duplicates.

Problem is, when I call my getColumn method, it returns an array consisting of only one number (for example 11111111, 22222222, 33333333). I have no idea why it does that. Here is my code:

```
int[][] sodokuColumns = new int[length][length];

for(int k = 0 ; k < sodokuPuzzle.length ; k++) {
    sodokuColumns[k] = getColumn(sodokuPuzzle, k);
}

for (int l = 0; l < sodokuPuzzle.length; l++) {
    if(uniqueEntries(sodokuColumns[l]) == false) {
        columnStatus = false;
    }
}
```

my helper is as follows

```
public static int[] getColumn(int[][] intArray, int index) {

    int[] column = new int[intArray.length];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < intArray.length ; i++) {
        column[i] = intArray[i][index];
    }
    return column; 
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: It's hard to say. What data is in sodokuPuzzle?

Comment: @Eskalior that would get rows, not columns, depending on how OP has defined them in their head.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> when I call my getColumn method, it returns an array consisting of only one number (for example 11111111, 22222222, 33333333).

I don't see any issue with your `getColumn` method other than the fact it's not even needed because `getColumn(sodokuPuzzle, k)` is the same as `sodokuPuzzle[k]`. If you're going to conceptualize your 2D array in such a way that your first index is the column then for your purpose of checking uniqueness you only need to write a method to get rows.

The issue you're having would seem to be with another part of your code that you did not share. I suspect there's a bug in the logic that accepts user input and that it's populating the puzzle incorrectly.

Lastly a tip for checking uniqueness (if you're allowed to use it) would be to create a `Set` of some kind (e.g. `HashSet`) and add all of your items (in your case integers) to that set. If the set has the same size as your original array of items then the items are all unique, if the size differs there are duplicates.